# How to break loop in Thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I need to break the `th:each` when after the first loop.is there any way to do that?
here the code that I tried.

```
<th:block th:each="prod, j : ${products}" th:if="${prod.type=='T'}">
    <span th:text="${prod.name}"></span>
</th:block>
```

result: all the T type product names

expect:the first T type product name only.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that template engines are not designed to execute complex logic. The best solution would be the put this logic in the controller and put the first product of type `'T'` in a separate attribute.

If that's not possible, another solution would be to write a Thymeleaf extension (or if using Spring a bean) that does this.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `th:each` for this, you can use [Collection Selection](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-collection-selection) to find the correct product.  For example, something like this:

```
<span th:with="selection=${products.?[type == 'T']}"
      th:text="${selection.size() > 0 ? selection[0].name : 'No product found'}" />
```